# why is id 'undefined' in this code?

Tags: javascript

Take the following js, the alert fires, but id is 'undefined'.  Can someone tell me why?  How can I invoke LoadPage with a parameter?

```
var arr = [];
arr.push(LoadPage);
arr[0].call(5);

function LoadPage(id) {
    alert(id);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're using the `.call` method to invoke your function, the first argument you pass sets the value of `this`.

So you'd need to do this instead:

```
arr[0].call(5); // you're setting the value of "this" in the function to "5"

function LoadPage(id) {
    alert( this );
}
```

If you don't need to explicitly set the value of `this`, but rather just want to pass an argument, then eliminate the `.call` part:

```
arr[0](5);  // now you're just passing an argument. The value of "this" in the
            //     function will be the "window" object

function LoadPage(id) {
    alert( id );
}
```

---

**EDIT:** To give a quick overview of how `this` gets its value in a function, consider this one function that will be called in several different ways:

```
function some_func() {
    alert( this );  // the value of "this" changes based on how it is called.
}

  // Calling it directly, "this" is the "window" object ( in browsers )
some_func();  // window


  // Calling it from an object's property, "this" will be that object
var some_obj = { foo:'bar', a_func:some_func };
some_obj.a_func();  // the object we used to reference the function


  // Calling it via the `.call` method, "this" will be that first argument
var some_obj = {foo:'bar'};
some_func.call( some_obj );  // the object referenced by some_obj


  // Calling it via the `.apply` method, "this" will be that first argument
var some_obj = {foo:'bar'};
some_func.apply( some_obj );  // the object referenced by some_obj

 // (The difference between `.call` and `.apply` is the manner in which
 //         they accept additional arguments passed to the function.)
```

In newer browsers, you can use `.bind()` to get a copy of the function that has its "this" value bound to it.

```
var some_obj = {foo:'bar'};
var new_func = some_func.bind( some_obj );

some_func(); // will be window
new_func();  // will be the object that we bound
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a different way to invoke the function when all I have is a reference to that function (not sure if 'reference' is the right term here)?

Comment: @John: Just remove `.call` if you don't need to explicitly set the value of `this`, like `arr[0](5)`. You're almost always invoking a function from a reference to it. It's just that the value of `this` inside the function changes based on *how* that function is invoked.

Comment: @John Your 2 options are using call() and apply(), which are extremely similar but vary only in how the arguments are handled.  Both take a scope/context (that which should be treated as 'this' in the method call).

Answer (score 3):

The first argument to `call()` is the object to which the `this` keyword is bound.

You should do this:

```
arr[0].call(arr[0], 5);
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [MDC docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Call):

```
fun.call(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])
```

The first argument you pass is what becomes the value of "this." The second one is the first real parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Using `.call()` sets the value of `this` in the function.  Try calling the function this way:

```
arr[0](5);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6D8wN/